# How to instantiate any class at runtime with any given number of arguments?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

Can someone point me in the right direction on how to instantiate any class
at runtime with any given number of arguments?

As an example and to be more precise, 
I included an example below.
How could I write this example in one line of code - ok, maybe two : )

```
// klass: an argument of type Class ( could be Sprite, Array, MyCustomClass, … )

switch( args.length )
{
    case 0:
        return new klass();
        break;
    case 1: 
        return new klass( args[0] );
        break;
    case 2:
        return new klass( args[0], args[1] );
        break;
    case 3:
        return new klass( args[0], args[1], args[2] );
        break;
    case 4:
        return new klass( args[0], args[1], args[2], args[3] );
        break;
    default:
        break;
}
```

Comment: unfortunately as you wrote it is the only solution. You can't use "apply" on the "new" operator, so there's no way to pass arguments to a constructor other than splitting them up (as you did), or letting the constructor accept an array.

Comment: @AsTheWormTurns: can you ellaborate on: "then you pass in `args.slice`"?  Should I do it in the constructor of a class?  Thanks for your insights.

Comment: @Webdevotion: sorry, after reading Creynders' reply I realized I hadn't understood well your question

Comment: @unkiwii: solution is in the answer itself.... lol

Comment: As @Creynders said, the solution is in the question itself, you may use a dictionary instead of a switch but in the end thats the solution, here a class that I made some time ago: http://bit.ly/uFZ2jl

Comment: @PranavHosangadi ups.. sorry (I'm not so good in English) I've edited the commentary already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My way of doing things seems to be the legit one as confirmed by the comments below my question.

Answer (score 0):

You could try accepting the ...rest parameter in your constructor, then doing a switch to allow for a variety of options.

```
package {
    public class Test {
        public function Test (...rest) {
            if (rest[0] is MovieClip) { ... }
        }
    }
}
```

For example ^^^